# Right-shift alone changes input source

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 14.10

Whenever I press and release right-shift without pressing another key, the input source changes. I can't find this shortcut listed in any of the keyboard or language control panels. I have four languages installed and I'm using English 98% of the time, so it's ridiculous that I have to keep switching it back whenever I should accidentally press right-shift.

Comment: Is it left Shift or right Shift that's experiencing this issue? Your question does not match your title.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was confused and I have fixed that. It is right-shift.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up System Settings.
2. Go to Keyboard in the Hardware section.
3. Navigate to Shortcuts tab.
4. Select Typing in the list of the left side pane.

There you should see some shortcut-keys name like "Switch to next source", "Switch to previous source". You could now modify these shortcut keys to what you would like to set.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, this control panel is no help. The modifiers are disabled, except for "Modifiers-only switch to next source" is set to "Scroll Lock" and "Compose Key" is set to Right Win. So where is right-shift coming from if it's not listed here?

Comment: Ah, by messing with all of the listed items in the control panel, I've managed to get the offending behavior to stop. The whole GUI wedges sometimes while I'm in that control panel, and language settings don't work quite as advertised, so I'm going to approach this with the understanding that the whole framework is very buggy. But I guess my question is moot now.

Comment: If you are not sure about where the shortcut key is assigned for input source, better assign yourself some shortcut keys for those I mentioned above in the Typing option in the Shortcuts tab.